# how to check the state of the row in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I want to check if the row is in edit mode.
I've checked the jqGrid documentation but I couldn't find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will check this for you:

```
var edited = "0";
var ind = jQuery("#myGrid").getInd(row_id,true);
if(ind != false){
    edited = $(ind).attr("editable");
}

if (edited === "1"){
    // row is being edited
} else{
    // row is not being edited
}
```

Comment: Is your answer works when using custom formatters? I'm using formatters in my grid and it alwasys shows row is edited even when i'm not editing it.

Comment: Good question - is it possible for you to post a small example demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Seems to me that just tells you if the row Can be edited not read only. Not if it is in Edit mode